# Text in Textfield starts in Middle of TextField IOS

Tags: ios, swift, alignment, textfield

Hello the placeholder text, and the text the user inputs, starts in the middle of my textfield. I have the textfield as 30% of the screen height, so I can't simply make the textfield smaller. 
How do I make the text start in the top left corner?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you want to do is both a `horizontal` and `vertical` alignment like this:

```
textField.textAlignment = .left
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = .top
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can choose top-left in Storyboard:

[image: 1]